# React refresh redirects to home with same url of the where page refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have react router dom to route from one component to another component. Mention the code below that am using for the routing inbetween the components.

```js
<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Language} exact />
        <Route path="/termsandconditions" component={TermsConditions} exact />
      </Switch>
</Router>
```

The actual problem in when I am in the url `/termsandconditions`, I refreshed the page it will redirect to the **Language component** with the url of `/termsandconditions`, If the URL is in `/termsandconditions` the **TermsConditions component** would get render while refresh the page.

Any solution for this while refreshing the page. It's would stayed in the component of the current URL.

Comment: Are you by any chance rendering more than one `Router` component in your app?

Comment: Nope this is the only component containing Router

Comment: There must be something else going on, as shown on this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-torvalds-ub6y9?file=/src/App.js) example, it works just fine with the code you provided.

Comment: My other hunch is that you've hosted your app somewhere the server/directory isn't configured correctly (something to do with the `.htaccess` file for requests to "nested" routes I believe). Your React app is technically a single-page-app and the router it merely manipulating the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have used a session storage to save your last route before page refresh event

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('lastRoute', JSON.stringify(window.location.pathname))
        }
```

Add the code above to your App.js useEffect and then you can access a session storage and get last route and redirect to it.